# Using Python to fourier transform Interofrogram to spatial frequency

Tags: python, image, signal-processing, fft, physics

so essentially i have a set of laser fringes projected onto a camera. I captured this image and converted it to greyscale. I perform a 2D fourier transform and i get the following image:

[image]

This is what i expected of course. Now the problem is I want to obtain something like this:
[image]

This is essentially the spatial frequency. I am trying to obtain the wavelength of the laser light captured by the image so i need to get an image like this to allow me to continue. But I am not sure how to get to this. Any help would be appreciated this is my code so far:

```
 image_greyscale = image.convert('1')
imgplot_greyscale = plt.imshow(image_greyscale)
plt.xlabel('Pixel X')
plt.ylabel('Pixel Y')
plt.title('Laser Image')
plt.show()
dark_image_grey_fourier = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(image_greyscale))
plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(8, 6), dpi=80)
plt.imshow(np.log(abs(dark_image_grey_fourier)), cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

Comment: You are sure you want to use Fourier Transform? Can you show example image?